# Magento add pager toolbar to wishlist

Tags: magento, pager

Is it possible to use the catalog collection pager for the wishlist, and if so how can I implement this into the wishlist?

Comment: @denny: +1 for same issue i got.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[danny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/810568/danny) (OP) already self-answered the question.

Quote:

---

Ok, i've found the solution [here](http://prakashkhandelwal.blogspot.com/2010/04/magento-pagination.html) but i'll post it here too for a better code highlighting:
Create a new modul and overwrite the wishlist block located in: `code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Block/Customer/Wishlist.php`
and add the following to your Wishlist.php

```
class Company_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist extends Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist
{
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()
                      ->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'wishlist.customer.pager')
                      ->setCollection($this->getWishlist());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getWishlist()->load();
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPagerHtml()
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }  
}
```

now add `<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>` to the start and/or end of the **view.phtml** located in: **app/design/frontend/default/your_theme/template/wishlist/view.phtml**. that should do the trick.

---

<sub>Note: It's absolutely [OK to self-answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/should-i-not-answer-my-own-questions/12519#12519) your own question. Please just post it as an real answer, but *not* in a question or comment. Posting as real answer helps to keep the "Unanswered" list more clear (avoids making other people wasting their time).</sub>

Comment: @gowri hey gowri, this is working for me in magento 1.5.1.0 w/o problems, what errors you get?

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to create a new module.just create (with folder) in your local : app\code\local\Mage\Wishlist\Block\Customer\Wishlist.php.
and enter the following code on Wishlist.php

```
<?php class Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist extends Mage_Wishlist_Block_Abstract {
/**
 * Preparing global layout
 *
 * @return Mage_Wishlist_Block_Customer_Wishlist
 */
protected function _prepareLayout()
{
    parent::_prepareLayout();
    $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html_pager', 'wishlist.customer.pager');
    $pager->setAvailableLimit(array(5=>5,10=>10,20=>20,'all'=>'all'));
    $pager->setCollection($this->getWishlist());
    $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
    $this->getWishlist()->load();
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Pager HTML
 *
 * @return HTML
 */
public function getPagerHtml()
{
    return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
}
```

`}`

After that add following code in /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/wishlist/view.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getPagerHtml(); ?>
```

after title div and after formkey in end of view.phtml

: [image example](http://i.imgur.com/9d4wQLi.png)

tested on Magento ver. 1.9.0.1